Replace left click with alternative shortcut for drag and drop
Slowly but somehow suddenly, my pc (Ubuntu) does not see anymore the left click (and also not the right click, so no click in general). However, I can tap on the touchpad as always. My problem is that I am unable to use drag and drop techniques, since I cannot keep the click pressed.
Can I change configuration, and assign the click to some other key, or is there an alternative method already set up in Ubuntu?

Of course you have already tried another mouse to see if it is a hardware problem?

I don't have another mouse at disposal right now :( But I can soon try on Windows to see if there it works normally. However, it was working less-and-less well with time during the past 10 weeks, so I supposed it was a hardware problem

@David, yes also on Windows it doesn't work anymore, but the touchpad works. Maybe there's just some dust inside and I should open the computer and clean it.

Your issue was with your touchpad, right? Not with a mouse?

When you have Tap to Click enabled (Settings → Mouse & Touchpad → Touchpad tab → Tap to Click), you can use drag and drop as follows:

Double-tap the touchpad without releasing the second tap.

Then drag the item to the place you want and drop it there by releasing the tap.



Very simply, I solved issue by blowing under the pad to blow dust away and everything started working again.
